# Using Lombok @SuperBuilder annotation with toBuilder on an abstract class?

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following classes:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class Parent {
    //...
}

@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Child extends Parent {
    //...
}

@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Child2 extends Parent {
    //...
}
```

Why am I unable to call `toBuilder()` on an instance of the abstract class (`Parent`) as shown in the following code?

```
public copy(Parent parent) {
    parent.toBuilder().build();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, as [Hossein Nasr already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633821/using-tobuilder-in-lombok-on-abstract-class-annotated-with-superbuilder/61633890#61633890), Lombok cannot know whether there are subclasses that do not have `toBuilder=true`.

Lombok could require all direct subclasses of an abstract class to also use `toBuilder` by adding an `abstract toBuilder()` method on the abstract class. However, there may be use-cases where subclasses should not have a `toBuilder` (although I haven't seen any good examples of those). Furthermore, indirect subclasses may still lack the `toBuilder` feature. Therefore, lombok does not enforce `toBuilder` on subclasses of abstract classes.

Good news is that you can easily work around it in your case (only direct subclasses) by adding the `abstract toBuilder()` method to your `abstract class Parent` manually:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class Parent {
    public abstract ParentBuilder<?, ?> toBuilder();
}
```

With this change, your `copy` method compiles and works as expected.

If you also have indirect subclasses, you have to find other means to ensure they also have `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)`. If those would not have this annotation, you may experience strange behavior (e.g. calling `copy()` will instantiate a different class).

*Disclaimer:* I implemented the `@SuperBuilder` feature.

Comment: Would making the direct subclasses `final` to avoid indirect subclass issues make sense or would that break something that takes place under the covers in Lombok?

Comment: You can do that, it won't break anything. However, it's no guarantee, because someone could still inherit from your abstract base class, doing funny things with `toBuilder()` or something similar.

Comment: Could you explain why (or if) this works only for direct subclasses?

Comment: I think you mean that you'd need to add a method to each abstract class in the hierarchy, which is no big deal. I think all this should be documented. And this answer should be shortened to just say, "declare it yourself."

Comment: No, you just need to put it on the topmost abstract class. I added a paragraph on indirect subclasses (those will work if they also have `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)`).

Comment: What exactly is `toBuilder=true` doing? Lombok documentation is unclear on this.

Comment: If you want to know how a lombok annotation or parameter _exactly_ works, just run delombok and have a look at the generated code.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because Lombok can not guarantees that every child class of `Parent` is also marked as `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)` and if so, Lombok can not call the `toBuilder` of that instance;