# Lombok @SuperBuilder on abstract class with generic cause error: incompatible types

Tags: java, lombok

I have abstract class with generic type. it has abstract toBuilder method as suggested here: [Using Lombok @SuperBuilder annotation with toBuilder on an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633821/using-lombok-superbuilder-annotation-with-tobuilder-on-an-abstract-class)

### here is the abstract class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class TenantConfItem<T extends DeepCloneable<T>> {

    private final URN urn;

    private final Long version;

    private final T configData;

    public abstract TenantConfItemBuilder<T, ?, ?> toBuilder();

    public TenantConfItem<T> copy() {
        return this.toBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

the subtype:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicy extends TenantConfItem<ExpirationByEarnedDate> implements Singleton {

}
```

here I'm using its builder:

```
val policyBuilder = PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicy.builder()
                .version(0L)
                .configData(new ExpirationByEarnedDate(retentionDays));
```

but I get an error for the configData:

```
error: incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to ?
                .configData(new ExpirationByEarnedDate(retentionDays));
                           ^
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicyBuilder<CAP#2,CAP#1> from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicy from capture of ?
```

I guess it is because the parent builder has 3 arguments with the generic (`TenantConfItemBuilder<T, ?, ?>`) and the sub one has 2 (`PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicyBuilder<?, ?>`).
Any idea for workaround?

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. Which lombok and Java version are you using? Try replacing `val` with the actual type (`PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicyBuilder<?, ?>`).

Comment: Wow! using PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicyBuilder<?, ?> instead of val solved the issue. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)` supports generic classes and refining the type parameter from the superclass in the subclass. So your classes and their annotations are fine.

However, lombok sometimes has problems inferring the correct type for `val`, especially when type parameters are involved.

The solution is to replace `val` with the actual type `PointsExpirationByEarnedDatePolicyBuilder<?, ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional note to the above workaround, if you check the bytecode of the builder that is generated when you declare the superbuilder, you will see that it uses wildcards, so you need to explicitly declare the type.

**Class**

```
@SuperBuilder public class User {
 private String name; 
}
```

**ByteCode**

```
// access flags 0x9
// signature ()Lorg/example/User$UserBuilder<**>;
// declaration: org.example.User$UserBuilder<?, ?> builder()
public static builder()Lorg/example/User$UserBuilder;
L0
LINENUMBER 5 L0
NEW org/example/User$UserBuilderImpl
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL org/example/User$UserBuilderImpl.<init> ()V
ARETURN
MAXSTACK = 2
MAXLOCALS = 0
```